# simulate a link(<a href='dd'>) click with javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, href, simulate

For some reason, I cannot use jquery.

With plain javascript, how could I simulate the link-click action on a web page.

Thanks.

Below is the javascript I tried to get online, but it seems not work.

```
function create_window (title, content){

    var comment = document.getElementById('modal'); 
alert(comment.innerHTML);
    if (comment.click) {
        alert('hi');
        comment.click();
    } else if (document.createEvent) {
        alert('3'); 
        var ev = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
         ev.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 12, 345, 7, 220, false, false, true, false, 0, null )
         comment.dispatchEvent(ev);
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function simulateClick() {
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  var cb = document.getElementById("link");
  var canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent). [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vNe4x/5/) is a fiddle, in which I define the function to create and dispatch the click event, add an event handler to the element, and call the function after a delay of 1 second.

Comment: hi Asad, with the fiddle, do you think I need to embed some library like jquery or motools to make it working?

Comment: Thanks, I think I see how it works now. just a small thing, in your case, it simulates the onclick event, is that possible for us to use this to simulate a click href link?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="doc.pdf"><span id="spnDownload">Download!</span></a>
```

$("#spnDownload").click();