# Fully simulate mouse interaction with a link

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have an element and a link. I want mouse interaction with the first element to behave exactly like it was the link. This means that

- left-clicking should navigate to the href
- ctrl+clicking should open in a new foreground tab
- middle-clicking should open in a new background tab
- shift+clicking should open in a new window.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raylu/3N4Sp/3/) for an example with a table row.

This works perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892598/simulate-a-linka-href-dd-click-with-javascript) is similar but doesn't ask about the non-left-click behavior and also doesn't work in Firefox.

Note that the [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) works fine in Firefox for left-clicking (and should be supported since MDN documents it) since you can see the `console.log`. By the way, you can't even catch middle-click `click` events, but you can listen for `mouseup` (or `mousedown`, but that would be silly).

It's possible to simulate the first two behaviors instead of just dispatching the event to the link and I don't care so much about the shift+click case, but [middle-click doesn't work in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background).

Comment: You can read the relevant properties of the event generated by the click event on the element, then assign them to a new event and dispatch it to the link. Not sure browsers will treat simulated clicks on links exactly as they will treat a real one though. I think it will be less than perfect in most browsers.

Comment: Yes... that's exactly what my fiddle does...

Comment: That's so hoaky ~ why not abstract a link into something, instead of something into a link. Do you know what does everything you need? A link.

Comment: Then show me how else to make the table row clickable. You can't wrap an `<a>` tag around a `<tr>`.

Comment: turns out CSS flexible boxes are basically tables. https://github.com/raylu/ykill/commit/58afea26ae1d8e6686ae034321d0eb42a2db4c7b